# Global variable in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

How can I have a global variable in a component that all the methods have access to it? I can't use the state because I have nested rendering and by changing the state of a variable I'm getting the warning that the render should be pure and don't use the `setState` inside render....! So I need to have a regular global variable accessible by all methods of the component and be able to change the value of it wherever is needed. Can anyone help me please?

P.S. Why I shouldn't change a state like this: `this.state.variable = true;`?

So here is my simplified code. `this.setState({hidden: true});` will make the warning because this component is rendering inside another component. I need to make `hidden` to behave like a global variable and don't use the state!

```
const Component = React.createClass({
    mixins: [React.addons.PureRenderMixin],
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {hidden: false};
    },

    renderFixedFields(.....) {
        var request_link;
        if (!this.state.hidden) {
            request_link = <Link to={`/${record.get('id')}/request`}>Send Request </Link>
        }
        else {
            request_link = null
        }
        return (
            <div>
                {request_link}
            </div>
           )
    },

    renderField(.....) {
        var self = this;
        //....
        if (fieldID == "open_access") {
            this.setState({hidden: true});
        }
        return (
            //.....
        );
    },

    renderFieldBlock(........) {
        const [maj, min] = getMajMinFields(s);
        //....
        const minFields = min.entrySeq().map(
            ([id, f]) => this.renderField(fieldID, .....));

        return (
            //...
            <div>
                { minorFields }
            </div>
        );
    },
}
```

Comment: and where is `fieldID` set?

Comment: @chasenyc Updated the question. `renderFieldBlock` is sending `fieldID` as an argument to `renderField `

Answer (score 0):

Setting state inside of `render()` is always going to be an issue as state changing will issue a `render()`. While the specific thing you are doing may not cause an issue, you should really be thinking about the lifecycle of your component and where that state really needs to change. If you need to change state based on new props then use [`componentWillReceiveProps`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-componentwillreceiveprops):

```
componentWillReceiveProps: function(nextProps) {
  this.setState({
    likesIncreasing: nextProps.likeCount > this.props.likeCount
  });
}
```

Comment: @ chasenyc : I need to have a boolean variable to be able to change it several times inside different methods. It's not passing to any other component, so it's not a prop. But the mixins (AFAIU) are only for changing props, right?

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit on what you are trying to achieve? Under what circumstances do you want this boolean to change?

Comment: @ chasenyc : I tried to make a summery of my code and updated my question. hope it helps to make my problem clear.